# SQL regular expression about number like '${year}%'

Tags: sql

I want to know what is this means in SQL:

```
number like '${year}%'
```

if anyone can help to explain it

Comment: Are you sure `${year}` is for SQL script?

Comment: yeah it is when creating a title

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: This looks like part of a PHP string...

Comment: `${year}` is probably replaced by the client before submitting the Select resutling in `number like '2018%'`